# python average bitrate per second

Tags: python, average, bitrate

I have a `txt` file that looks like this:

```
0.065998       81   
0.319601      81   
0.539613      81  
0.768445      81  
1.671893      81  
1.785064      81  
1.881242      954  
1.921503      193  
1.921605      188  
1.943166      81  
2.122283      63  
2.127669      83  
2.444705      81
```

The first column is the packet arrival and second packet size in bytes.

I need to get the average value of bytes in each second. For example in the first second I have only packets with value 81 so the average bitrate is `81*8= 648bit/s`. Then I should plot a graph x axis time in seconds, y axis average bitrate in each second.

So far I have only managed to upload my data as arrays:

```
import numpy as np

d = np.genfromtxt('data.txt')

x = (d[:,0])  
y = (d[:,1 ])

print x  
print(y*8)
```

I'm new to Python, so any help where to start would be much appreciated!

Here is the result script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
x, y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)  
bins = np.arange(60+1)  
totals, edges = np.histogram(x, weights=y, bins=bins)  
counts, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)  

print counts  
print totals*0.008/counts  

plt.plot(totals*0.008/counts, 'r')  
plt.xlabel('time, s')  
plt.ylabel('kbit/s')  
plt.grid(True)  
plt.xlim(0.0, 60.0)  
plt.show()
```

The script reads the .txt file which contains packet size(bytes) and arrival time, and plots the average bitrate/s during a time period. Used to monitor server incoming/outgoing traffic!

Comment: In the first second, you only have received 81*4 bits, correct?

Comment: Could you specify your definition of "average bitrate". Do want the average since the beginning of the data? Or a more recent estimate of the average?

Comment: Yes in the first second I have received 4 packets 81bytes each. I want to get the average packet size in bits in each second. Lets say we received 10 packets each different size in the first second, so I need to get the average value in bits for those 10packets in the first second... and so on for every next second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `numpy`, you can use [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x, y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)
>>> bins = np.arange(10+1)
>>> totals, edges = np.histogram(x, weights=y, bins=bins)
>>> totals
array([  324.,  1578.,   227.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.])
```

This gives the total in each bin, and you could divide by the width of the bin to get an approximate instantaneous rate:

```
>>> totals/np.diff(bins)
array([  324.,  1578.,   227.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.])
```

(Okay, since the bin widths were all one, that isn't very interesting.)

[update]

I'm not sure I understand your follow-up comment that you need the average packet size in each second -- I don't see that mentioned anywhere in your question, but I'm notorious at missing the obvious.. :-/  In any case, if you want the number of packets in a time bin, then you simply don't need to set the weights (default is 1):

```
>>> counts, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
>>> counts
array([4, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

where counts is the number of packets which arrived in each bin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This almost does the job, from this I get the total bits transferred per second in all packages that arrived in that second. But I need to get the average packet size in each second. I need to divide the result that I get from totals with len(y) in that second, since I get irregular number of packets each second. How can I calculate len(y) in each second?

Comment: Many thanks! I have edited the code in the first post if you are interested to see what I meant by average. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your data is already sorted by time so I might just use `itertools.groupby` for this one:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('data.txt') as d:
     data = ([float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in d)
     for i_time,packet_info in groupby(data,key=lambda x:int(x[0])):
         print i_time, sum(x[1] for x in packet_info)
```

output is:

```
0 324.0
1 1578.0
2 227.0
```

Comment: Good answer although OP wanted average.

Comment: @sotapme -- I'm not exactly sure what OP meant by "average bytes in each second".

Comment: You're right it does read confusingly - I'd presumed he had 4 samples in 1 second of 81, which was an average of 81 ; then times that by 8 for bit rate. Whatever - your answer has put got them 90% of the way there and the rest is mere detail.

Answer (score 0):

Since the arrival times are irregular, I recommend quantizing them into integer numbers of seconds, and then aggregating total bytes for all arrivals for a given second. With this done, plotting and other analysis gets a lot easier.